# Android Activity close automatically

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, heap-memory

I built an app which displays information from a city.

I successfully ran a few tests with my Samsung Galaxy S5 and on a couple more devices using the built in emulator from Android Studio.

If I use for instance the Samsung S3 Mini (Android 4.1.2, 1GB Ram) it opens the first Activity. In the Main Activity I built a switch case statement to move to my other Activities:

```
switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.aktuelles:
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "aktuelles wurde geklickt");
            i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            break;

        case R.id.ideen_maengel:
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "ideen_maengel wurde geklickt");
            openSubMenu(ideen_maengel_sub, ideenmaengel_arrow_top, ideenmaengel_arrow_bottom);
            scrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, ideen_maengel.getTop());
                }
            }, 1);
            break;

        case R.id.neue_meldung:
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "neue_meldung wurde geklickt");
            i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MaengelActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
```

After I click on the button it moves in the Activity but immediately closes the Activity after 2 seconds and automatically moves back to the previous Main Activity. It looks like a Heap problem, which is why I cannot cache the Activity.

On devices like the Samsung Galaxy S4 or devices with higher API levels it works perfectly.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to resolve this error?

Some users have the same problem with following devices:

- Galaxy S3 Neo Plus
- HTC Desire 610
- Galaxy S4 Mini
- Xperia X Compact

Comment: is there any error in your log ? what is your next activity 'oncreate'?

Comment: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 1ms
Duplicate finish request for ActivityRecord{ad37c7d8 u0 de.bluebox.dirk.casapp/.MenuActivity t2 f}
START u0 {cmp=de.bluebox.dirk.casapp/.MenuActivity} from pid 2620
startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { cmp=de.bluebox.dirk.casapp/.MenuActivity }
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1059K, 10% free 57284K/62992K, paused 4ms, total 6ms
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 12873K, 25% free 56954K/75536K, paused 6ms, total 6ms 
Displayed de.bluebox.dirk.casapp/.MenuActivity: +205ms

Comment: START u0 {cmp=de.bluebox.dirk.casapp/.MenuActivity} from pid 2620 startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { cmp=de.bluebox.dirk.casapp/.MenuActivity } Logging event (FE): _e, Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=1883, _sc=MenuActivity, _si=-3993089302546656757}]

Comment: That is the Log after switching the the Activity.

Comment: In the next activity 'oncreate' I only set the ContentView, check the internet connection and set a click event for a back button..

Answer (score 0):

Just Select the *No filter* option in the logcat.
You will be able to find the reason behind the app close. Then you can figure it out.

I faced this situation when I was trying to fetch the data from the URL which does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung M51 face Same issue

Without any error

just start the intent
it will auto close on back press without write the finish

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score -1):

Which button does this? 
Which switch case is being hit?

I bet it's the first one that does…

```
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
```

^ Why do you do Finish? Your activity will be paused, stopped and *possibly* destroyed after you go to another one, you don't need to finish the current one.

Comment: finish() was only a test to destroy the previous activity to clean the heap.. Without finish it does not work, too.

Comment: Then remove it from the question. Also, can you provide a crash log in a normal format, edit your question and explain your problem, we can't perform acts of magic and tell you why your app is closing without seeing the code and the crash log. If you didn't have a problem, you wouldn't be posting the question, so the whole _In the next activity 'oncreate' I only set the ContentView, check the internet connection and set a click event for a back button_ is obviously not true, something you're doing is wrong and we were trying to help.